# Logic behind a monitor program

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am currently trying to solve the 'unisex bathroom' problem found in [this book],(http://greenteapress.com/semaphores/LittleBookOfSemaphores.pdf) the constraints are:
- if the bathroom is empty, either male or female can enter
- if a male or female is in the bathroom, only the same gender can enter
- there can only be two people in the bathroom already

What is confusing me is although I have some understanding of the concepts of how the logic works, I am not sure where/how to implement this code. Eg, I have a class named 'employee' which extends thread and can set a variable that shows if they are male or female. I also have a 'bathroom' class that also extends thread that contains the semaphore called 'being used' which is to determine if the bathroom is full. I was trying to implement the lightswitch structure found in the book, which i assume is just a monitor. I do not understand how this locks for a specific type of thread.

My question is, where do I store the semaphore variables, and what is the best way to access them in order to implement the rest of the logic?

EDIT: When I refer to the lightswitch I mean the struct on page 70, and the bathroom problem is located on page 170.

Bathroom class contains:

```
  Semaphore being_used = new Semaphore(1);
```

Employee class contains:

```
    private String id;
    private int time;
    private String type;
    private Boolean finished;
    private Bathroom b_room;
```

Comment: Re, "I also have a 'bathroom' class that also extends thread..." That probably is a bad idea. In this analogy, the male and female people represent two different categories of thread, and the bathroom represents a _resource_ that the threads need to share in a particular way. The bathroom object therefore needs an API that allows a thread to perform at least two operations; (1) Await permission and then "enter," and (2) "leave". You may want it to have other methods that improve the demo (e.g., a method to find out who is "in" the bathroom, methods to find out how long the've been there, etc.)

Comment: I have since changed it so that threads run, then they call startUsing and stopUsing which uses the semaphores to access the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without reading the book... A semaphore belongs to the bathroom: if you had three bathrooms and seven users, you would have three semaphores, not one, not seven. A semaphore licence should be acquired whenever bathroom is applied for entrance by a user, and released whenever an exit message is sent to it, or an entering user is denied entry.

Comment: So you think I should run each thread and they will run the logic inside the bathroom code?

Comment: In my opinion, agents should be threads; bathroom is not agentive, it just responds (synchronously) to events posted by agents. But all of this can be modelled many different ways.

Comment: The lightswitch works by taking in a semaphore and a count, every time the function lock is called it increments a value and makes the semaphore locked, but I still dont understand how to filter it so only one type goes through

Comment: So, "lightswitch" = "counting semaphore"? As I said, many ways to do it. The simplest way would be to have a method `enter` on `Bathroom`, which would acquire the semaphore (increasing its count by 1); if that is successful (limit is not reached), and bathroom is empty, set the bathroom gender to user gender. Otherwise, check bathroom gender against user gender; if unequal, release the semaphore and reject the user. Otherwise, accept the user into the bathroom. In `exit` method, just release the semaphore, then reset gender if empty.